$\mathcal{A}=\{A \subset \mathbb{R}^{d} : A \ \text{is dense in} \ \mathbb{R}^{d} \ or \ \mathbb{R}^{d}-A \ \text{is dense in} \ \mathbb{R}^{d}\}$
Consider $\mathcal{A}=\{A \subset \mathbb{R}^{d} : A \ \text{is dense in} \ \mathbb{R}^{d} \ or \ \mathbb{R}^{d}-A \ \text{is dense in} \ \mathbb{R}^{d}\}$
I need to check whether $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$ algebra or not. I got,
Null set and $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ belong to $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{A}$ is closed under complementation.
To show that $\mathcal{A}$ is closed under countable union, three cases arise. Let's look into the finite union.
For $A,B \in \mathcal{A}$

$A$ and $B$ are dense.
Either $A$ or $B$ is dense.
Neither $A$ nor $B$ is dense. (their complements are dense)

When the case is 1 and 2, $A \cup B$ is dense. There is some trouble in dealing with the third case, I tried counter examples, but it is not working. May be the dense sets that I know won't help here, I am unable to conclude whether $\mathcal{A}$  is $\sigma$ algebra or not!

What examples have you tried?

I checked for sets which are not dense in $\mathbb{R}$, I tried with $\mathbb{Q} \cap (1,2)$ and ${\sqrt{2}}$, ${0}$ and ${1}$

Hint: try $A = \mathbb{Q} \cap (0, 1)$ and $B = (\mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Q}) \cap (0, 1)$.

@DavidGao I wonder why I didn't think of these... Thank you!
